# I need to write generate_count function returns the function which returns the value increased by 1 and you can send the start value of count into fun

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the code which does the first part of task: it returns the count of calls of function

```
def counter():
    val = [0]
    def generate_count():
        val[0] += 1
        return val[0]
    return generate_count

generate_count = counter()
print(generate_count())
```

But also I must be able to send start value of count into the func. As I know if u enter in ur function that u need to pass arguments then u are not be able to leave value blank. For example: If u write like this

```
def func1(n):
```

then you must pass one argument to make it work otherwise it wont work, so how to make it possible to work if u pass any arguments else if u don`t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a default value:

```
def func1(n=0):
   <code>
```

This function can be called with a parameter `n`, or it can be called without `n`. If you call the function like this:

```
func1()
```

The value of the parameter `n` will be set to 0, as you didn't specify a value.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably make more sense to use a builtin generator for this case.

```py
def counter(n=0):
    while True:
        n += 1
        yield n

generate_count = counter(1)
print(next(generate_count)) # > 2
```